# Runtime serialize condition with Genson

Tags: java, json, genson

Is it possible with Genson to conditionally serialize an object property at runtime? In other words to include/exclude a property at runtime due to a condition?

I've read of a RuntimePropertyFilter in the doc but no examples on how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/ext/jaxrs/UrlQueryParamFilter.java. Can you describe the kind of logic you would have to decide if a property should be ser/de?

Comment: The deserialize part is always on the complete object but I have a boolean during runtime that will tell me if I have to serialize the complete object or only a part of it.

Comment: is the Boolean value inside the object being ser or somewhere outside (so you know its value before starting the serialization)? If this is the case you can implement it with a runtime property filter. Otherwise you probably want a custom serializer.

Comment: The boolean condition is outside so the RuntimePropertyFilter is what I believed could work. Do you know an example use of it?

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment. This is an implementation that currently exists in Genson for jaxrs apps. You can inspire your self from there.